# How to stop Chrome from autocompleting text areas?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, textarea

I am dealing with a text area in part of a contact form that Chrome wants to autofill with the user's address. As a result many contact requests are submitted by users with their address in the comment field. Besides the obvious potential security issues that could be exploited, my concern is that from a user's standpoint we're providing a contact form without an area to type a message. And from a support standpoint, we're having to ask users to send us another message with their actual question.

HTML:

```
 <textarea id="element_10" class="validate[required] floatlabel js-auto-size multiple-lines" name="element_10" placeholder="Message*" rows="10" cols="60" required autocomplete="off"></textarea>
```

Comment: Whoever finds this, here's an older SO question that seems to be continuously updated: [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Answer (score 12):

Answering my own question since I did not find the answer on Stack or in any Chrome browser docs.

> In some cases, the browser will keep suggesting autocompletion values
>   even if the autocomplete attribute is set to off. This unexpected
>   behavior can be quite puzzling for developers. The trick to really
>   forcing the no-autocompletion is to assign a random string to the
>   attribute, for example:
>
> `autocomplete="nope"`
>
> Since this random value is not a valid one, the browser will give up.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: Actually may not help in all cases. More details in Chrome bug discussion:  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914451#c99

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions and nothing really worked consistently.

If I set one input to autocomplete="nope" it works.

If I set two or more it breaks them all.

If I set two to autocomplete="nope" and autocomplete="no" it works on those two but breaks again if I do anything to a 3rd.

My form only has 3 inputs.  I just set email and phone and left name alone. That pretty much solves my problem.

I have some jquery validation that pretty much does not work with autocomplete and this client really does not want to be bothered with junk emails.

Also Chrome treats a one row textarea exactly the same as a input.