# How can I disable autocomplete for this text area using js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, autocomplete, disable

How can I disable autocomplete for this textarea using javascript?

```
<textarea placeholder = "Send your concern..." id = "concern" class = "mako autoOff"></textarea>

.mako{
resize: vertical;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `autocomplete:off;` ? <textarea placeholder = "Send your concern..." id = "concern" autocomplete="off"></textarea>

Comment: @Manjuboyz yea, i did `<script>$(document).ready(function(){
$(".autoOff").attr("autocomplete","off");
});</script>`

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43217431/how-to-stop-chrome-from-autocompleting-text-areas

Comment: @BenjaminSloutsky I meant you already have browser property to hanlde in HTML directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `autocomplete="off";` you don't have to use `css` for this.

```
 <textarea placeholder = "Send your concern..." id = "concern" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
```

Comment: I have to reload the page for the text not to be shown, can it just automatically be always turned off, I tried what you suggested me to do.

Comment: Hmmmm strange, there is no need to refresh the page for this, it automatically starts implementing..... can you clear cache of the browser and try once? also remove the jquery code when you try.

Comment: I did, and it doesnt really work, I also remove jquery stuff

Comment: I am trying here trial and error! can you try `autocomplete;false;`? and which is the browser are you working with

Comment: I am on google, <textarea placeholder = "Send your concern..." id = "concern" class = "mako" autocomplete; "false;"></textarea>, I tried it and it didnt really work

Comment: it should be `autocomplete="false"` same goes with `autocomplete="off"` there is not semicolon after `false` or `off`, I added wrong text in my previous comment!

Comment: Is this correct? <textarea placeholder = "Send your concern..." id = "concern" class = "mako" autocomplete= "false"></textarea>

Comment: Yeah, looks good. When you say you're on google what does that mean!